# How do I prevent systemd from running my timer after reboot

Tags: linux, bash, centos, systemd, centos-7

I have the following oneshot service+timer :

```
$ systemctl cat stop_syncro.service stop_syncro.timer
# /usr/local/lib/systemd/system/stop_syncro.service
[Unit]
Description=Service d_arret de la Synchro
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
ExecStart=/root/shl/RUN/stop_syncro.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# /usr/local/lib/systemd/system/stop_syncro.timer
[Unit]
Description=Timer d_arret de la Synchro
[Timer]
OnCalendar=Mon-Fri *-*-* 8:00:00
[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Then I rebooted the server :

```
$ last reboot | head -1
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1160.71.1 Tue May 30 17:53 - 15:02  (21:09)
```

And it appears the service has been run right after the reboot

```
$ journalctl -u stop_syncro.service
-- Logs begin at Tue 2023-05-30 17:53:15 CEST, end at Wed 2023-05-31 14:48:17 CEST. --
May 30 17:53:26 PAR-SCAL-01 systemd[1]: Starting Service d_arret de la Synchro...
May 30 17:53:27 PAR-SCAL-01 systemd[1]: Started Service d_arret de la Synchro...
May 31 08:00:01 PAR-SCAL-01 systemd[1]: Starting Service d_arret de la Synchro...
May 31 08:00:02 PAR-SCAL-01 systemd[1]: Started Service d_arret de la Synchro...
$
```

How do I prevent my oneshot service to be only triggered at 8am instead of beeing also launched after reboot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not `[Install]` the service into `multi-user.target`. I strongly suspect it's not being run by the timer – it's being run on boot because you asked it to be run on boot, by placing it in multi-user.target.

So `systemctl disable` the .service, and maybe remove its [Install] section to prevent it from being accidentally re-enabled in the future.

Comment: Additionally, `RefuseManualStart=yes` could be used.

Comment: @user1686 In short, I need to remove the `[Install]` section only from the service, right ?

Comment: @SebMa They section does nothing on its own. The key part is that the service that must not be “enabled”.

Comment: @SebMa: From the service, yes. Roughly speaking, when the standard .targets are being used – If you "enable" a .timer unit, you're asking to start scheduling the timer on boot. If you "enable" a .service unit, you're asking to start the service on boot. It's not needed for manual or timer-based start.